# Android - Generate .APK

Tags: android, eclipse, version, android-manifest

I developed a project in Eclipse with API 4.0. and is running in the emulator perfeitamene 2.3.3. My phone has android 2.3.4. before generating mine. apk android I changed the Manifest for:

android: minSdkVersion = "8"
android: targetSdkVersion = "17"

But I can only open the home screen of the app on my phone. I downloaded an application to view the log of the device and the message is "Try to star activity" but is just on a black screen.

thank you

Comment: Could my answer help you a little bit ?

Answer (score 0):

Set targetSdkVersion = "10"
and test it

**android:targetSdkVersion**

An integer designating the API Level that the application targets. If not set, the default value equals that given to minSdkVersion.

This attribute **informs** the system **that you have tested against the target version** and **the system should not enable any compatibility** behaviors to maintain your app's forward-compatibility with the target version. The application is still able to run on older versions (down to minSdkVersion).

You can disable such compatibility behaviors by specifying targetSdkVersion to match the API level of the platform on which it's running. For example, setting this value to "11" or higher allows the system to apply a new default theme (Holo) to your app when running on Android 3.0 or higher and also disables screen compatibility mode when running on larger screens (because support for API level 11 implicitly supports larger screens).

To maintain your application along with each Android release, you should increase the value of this attribute to match the latest API level, **then thoroughly test** your application on the corresponding platform version.

Comment: I have changed the targetSdkVersion = 10. When I run the app on my phone(android 2.3.4) its open the first activity normally, but when i press the button to go to my second activity only appears a black screen, and the log says:

trying to Lauch mysecondActivity
displayed mySecondActivity:+216ms

but only a black screen is displayed.

Comment: @user2628769 : That could be a misconfiguration in your development. Post a new question with your settings and code. **But the first Activity is ok !!**

Comment: sorry for the bad english.

Comment: @user2628769 : My english is not much better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178862/android-activity-open-on-the-emulator-but-not-in-device

I post the cod