# Android - Activity open on the emulator but not in device

Tags: android, android-activity, foreach, datasource

I develop a little project in android and run ok on the emulator, but in my device only the first Activity is shown.
here's the cod of my Second Activity...:

```
public class SecondActivity extends ListActivity {
//database Source
private DataSource datasource;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

datasource = new DataSource(this);
datasource.open();

File sdcard2 =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

for(File f: sdcard2.listFiles()){
            if(f.isFile()) {

             if(f.getName().endsWith("MP3")|| f.getName().endsWith("mp3")){
                // Comment comment = null;

                  MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                  mmr.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+'/'+f.getName());
                  String mus = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
                  String art = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
                  datasource.InsereMusica(art,mus);


                                    }

                        }
            }
//Get the itens for the ListView
List<String> values = datasource.getAll();

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
                setListAdapter(adapter);

                registerForContextMenu(getListView());

}
```

The XML :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The Manifest:

```
   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <activity android:name="Inicio" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <activity
        android:name="SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Blundell.Light" >




    </activity>
```

So, I run normally on emulator 2.3.3 but don't works on my device android 2.3.4

Have something wrong ?

Thank you.

Comment: did u try to set android:targetSdkVersion to 11 and try once..

Comment: So the second activity is initiated from the first activity?

Comment: @Sushil yes, I try and don't works

Comment: Does your physical Android device HAVE an external directory (External SD Card)?

Comment: @DroidMatt yes, the first activity is just a Button start

Comment: simple_list_item_1 is missing. Maybe you defined the id of the list wrongly?

Comment: You need not give a layout for `ListActivity`. It already has one.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using same layout for both activities?, I think you are using same layout as this line generally shows first activity layout :  `setContentView(R.layout.main);`